# Gcov is not generating any .gcda files when I run mutiple executables together by using a script.

Tags: gcov

I compiled all of my executables with proper gcov flags (.gcno files got generated) and when I run them individually, all .gcda files appears at the proper place.

But when all of them are run together using a script then no .gcda files are generated. I tried writing a code to start them using fork and execv one by one. That also does not help.

The problem is I can not run them individually to get the gcov report since it does not make sense for my project.

Can anybody help me regarding this.

Comment: I found the problem. Gcov has nothing to do with multiple programs running. My programs had infinite loops in them and killing them using ctrl+c. I added graceful termination using signal handler and properly exited from each executable. Now I am getting the .gcda files.